# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nt)}{4 n^2 - 1} $

Tags: power-series, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I am trying to find if this series is uniformly convergent: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nt)}{4 n^2 - 1} $$ 
So far I have (using the Weierstrass M-Test):
$$| \frac{\cos(2nt)}{4 n^2 - 1}| \le \frac{-1}{4 n^2 -1}$$
Now using the ratio test for:
$$a_n = -\frac{1}{4 n^2 -1}$$
$$\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \frac{4n^2 -1}{4(n+1)^2 - 1} = \frac{4n^2 - 1}{4n^2 + 8n -1}$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{4n^2 - 1}{4n^2 + 8n -1} = \frac{4}{4} = 1$$
Hence the test is inconclusive.
How can i prove that the series is not uniformly convergent?

Comment: The series is uniform convergent because $\sum\limits_n\frac1{4n^2-1}$ converges because $\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: It's well known that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4n^2-1}$ converges: why did you use the ratio test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series *is* uniformly convergent since for any $t$
$$\left|\frac{\cos(2nt)}{4n^2-1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Additionally,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2nt)}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\sin(t\!\!\!\!\!\pmod{\pi}).$$